# php list - to put items on separate lines

Tags: php, list, echo

I am not confident enough with this code to figure out how to change it so I hope someone can help me.  Its from a php doc for my google map directory.  I purchased the plugin and have spent days configuring the style.css to be how I want it to be but this part is in a php file so Im not confident playing around with it.  In the map settings there are two fields, one for phone number and one for location.  When the directory is showing on live page, it lists these two next to each other like "123 private street ph 09 1234564".  I need them to each display on a separate line so phone number is under address.  Can someone please help me with this code so it will do that.  The code is:

```php
<p>
  <?php echo trim($list['qcpd_item_subtitle']); ?>
  <?php if(isset($list['qcpd_item_phone'])&&$list['qcpd_item_phone']!='') {
    echo '<span style="display:block;font-size:11px">';

    if(isset($list['qcpd_item_location']) and $list['qcpd_item_location']!=''){
      echo ' <span style="font-weight:bold">'.$list['qcpd_item_location'].'</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;';
    }
    echo ($phone_number=='1'?'<span class="sbd_phone"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> '.str_replace(array('(',')'),array('',''),$list['qcpd_item_phone']).'</span>':'');

    echo '</span>';

  }?>  
</p>
</div>
```

many thanks
Julie

Comment: Try adding a '<br>' in the echo statement where you want the line break.

Comment: Try using `<div></div>` instead of `<span></span>` or wrap the span inside a div

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<br />` *(line break)* after `<span>` with location, or change the `<span>` tags to `<div>`.

#### With `<br />`

```php
<p>
  <?php echo trim($list['qcpd_item_subtitle']); ?>
  <?php if(isset($list['qcpd_item_phone'])&&$list['qcpd_item_phone']!='') {
    echo '<span style="display:block;font-size:11px">';

    if(isset($list['qcpd_item_location']) and $list['qcpd_item_location']!=''){
      echo ' <span style="font-weight:bold">'.$list['qcpd_item_location'].'</span><br />';
    }
    echo ($phone_number=='1'?'<span class="sbd_phone"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> '.str_replace(array('(',')'),array('',''),$list['qcpd_item_phone']).'</span>':'');

    echo '</span>';

  }?>  
</p>
```

#### With `<div></div>`

```php
<p>
  <?php echo trim($list['qcpd_item_subtitle']); ?>
  <?php if(isset($list['qcpd_item_phone'])&&$list['qcpd_item_phone']!='') {
    echo '<div style="display:block;font-size:11px">';

    if(isset($list['qcpd_item_location']) and $list['qcpd_item_location']!=''){
      echo ' <div style="font-weight:bold">'.$list['qcpd_item_location'].'</div> &nbsp;&nbsp;';
    }
    echo ($phone_number=='1'?'<div class="sbd_phone"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> '.str_replace(array('(',')'),array('',''),$list['qcpd_item_phone']).'</div>':'');

    echo '</div>';

  }?>  
</p>
```

There should not be any difference between both approaches, however, because `<div></div>` is automatically followed by line-break it might break your tooltip/item style.

Comment: Thank you so much, the top one works perfectly. very grateful <3